# Solution for implementation dynamic generic abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, abstract

Hey I've got code like this

```
public abstract class SqlQueryDynamicTmpl<TSelf, TParams, TResult> : 
SqlCmdQueryInternalBase<TParams, TResult>
where TSelf : SqlQueryDynamicTmpl<TSelf, TParams, TResult>, new()
where TParams : class, SqlCmdQueryInternalBase<TParams, TResult>.IParams
where TResult : class, SqlCmdQueryInternalBase<TParams, TResult>.IResult, new()
```

I'm trying to "simplify" some dynamic generic abstract class for situation where `TParams` are other for each of inherited generic class but the same for Result.

I've try do something like this:

```
public abstract class SqlQueryDynamicGetCbmClients<TParams> : 
SqlQueryDynamicTmpl<SqlQueryDynamicGetCbmClients<TParams>
    ,TParams,SqlQueryDynamicGetCbmClients<TParams>.Result>,IParams
    where TParams:class, SqlQueryDynamicGetCbmClients<TParams>.IParams
```

but an error occured with information:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0310  'SqlQueryDynamicGetCbmClients' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TSelf' in the generic type or method

Does anybody know how I should try to make it?

Comment: Can you just reduce the names so they're not a kilometer long? Just say Derived and Base or A/B or something, they don't really matter, you know?

Comment: Although this is not an answer to the question as posted, I'm still going to throw it out there: if the SQL access in question is SQL Server, consider using Dapper or EF instead of whatever you're hand-rolling here. Even if an existing ORM is not the answer, consider *not* using generics and seeing how far that gets you. At some point it stops making sense to plug in ever more generic classes as opposed to lists, dictionaries, delegates, virtual methods, anonymous types or `dynamic`. When the first line of your class is four lines long, that point may have been reached.